# SolrNet compatible to Solr's which version?

Tags: solrnet

I am able to get the latest version of SolrNet from [here](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt290&tab=buildTypeHistoryList&guest=1). Yet I couldn't find some info from the [helplink](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/README.md).

Is this the latest version?

Also I would like to know about next release of SolrNet.

And please tell , "SolrNet-0.4.0.2002" is compatible with which version of [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html)?

Comment: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/FAQ.md#what-version-of-solr-do-i-need-does-solrnet-work-with-the-latest-release-of-solr

Answer (score 0):

Solr (3.1+) version is compatible based on this [link](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/FAQ.md#what-version-of-solr-do-i-need-does-solrnet-work-with-the-latest-release-of-solr)